# C# ADO.NET Parametrized query

Tags: c#, .net, ado

I have a T-SQL and query:

```
string queryString = @"SELECT AGENT.Number, PERSON.LoginName, AGENT.EnterpriseName FROM Agent AGENT INNER JOIN Person PERSON ON AGENT.PersonID = PERSON.PersonID WHERE LOWER(EnterpriseName) LIKE @entname";

string connStr = null;

try
{
    connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString + ToInsecureString(Decrypt(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["admin"])) + ";";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logs.WriteMessage("Error while making connStr " + ex.TargetSite + ex.StackTrace + ex.ToString());
}

try
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
        {
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@entname",
                        Value = "'%" + agentName + "%'"
                    };
            command.Parameters.Add(param);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    login = (string)reader[1];
                    userID = (string)reader[0];
                }
            }
        }

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

And this doesn't work. I get no result, but when I use value in query instead `@parameter` I get correct result.

Parameter `@entname` doesn't replaced to value so the query failed. Please give me a hint.

When I stop at breakpoint and see the query it looks that:

```
SELECT AGENT.Number, PERSON.LoginName, AGENT.EnterpriseName 
FROM Agent AGENT 
INNER JOIN Person PERSON ON AGENT.PersonID = PERSON.PersonID 
WHERE LOWER(EnterpriseName) LIKE @entname
```

So nothing changed.

Comment: The query will look the same under the debugger, it's not doing a string replace. How do you know it is failing?

Comment: Failed as in error?  Or failed as in an empty reader?  Get rid of those single quotation marks in the value.

Comment: Because I don't get a valid result, but when I use value in query instead @parameter I get correct result

Comment: not strictly related: you try catch the creation if the connection string. if there is an error, you log it (ok) and keep on as nothing happened (not ok). What is the following code expected to do if `connstring` is null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Parameter @entname doesn't replaced to value so the query failed.

That's not how parameters work.  The `@entname` parameter marker stays in the query that is sent to SQL Server, along with the matching parameter value.

So with that misunderstanding, you're quoting the parameter value as if it was going to be pasted into the SQL query:

```
Value = "'%" + agentName + "%'"
```

which you should not do.  Instead do

```
Value = "%" + agentName + "%"
```

Comment: Additionally, you will likely want to escape `agentName` - `public static string SqlLikeEscape(this string value)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                return value;
            }

            return Regex.Replace(value, @"(?<ch>%|_|\[)", @"[${ch}]");
        }` Otherwise `agentName` searches will act oddly in some cases (e.g. if the Agent Name is `mjw%wills`.